# Module exists in package.json but not found on firebase

Tags: npm, google-cloud-functions, next.js, package.json

I have a module in my nextjs project which is mentioned under dependencies in package.json. It works locally. But when I build and deploy to firebase function I get the following error

Cannot find module 'react-lazyload'

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export",
    "predeploy": "next build",
    "deploy": "firebase use  popcorntales-40767 & firebase deploy"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cacheable-response": "^2.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-chartkick": "^0.4.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.0.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.9",
    "react-share": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Commands used

```
1) next build
2) firebase deploy
```

Comment: could you at least share a copy of your package.json file? it's really hard to help you w/o seeing anything, also your deployment pipeline commands sequence would be helpful as well

Comment: @andresmijares updated the question

Comment: there was a known error in the past, it seems to be solved in a newer version, give it a try to see, instead of running `next build`, run it through the package.json, meaning `npm run build` instead.

Comment: Does `next build` compile successfully for you on local?

Comment: yes, it works fine. Even next start works fine after that and locally I am able to serve the UI.

Comment: Are you deploying the code to Firebase functions? Are you using private modules? Have you tried building/installing with npm? Lastly, if you're able to share a gist with a minimum reproducible code example so that we can test on our own would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes Firebase functions.
Yes tried it with npm as well..

Comment: I don't think we can do much without a reproducible code sample to work upon.